Issuse with relationship mapping MapKeyEnumerated with an Entity List as values
I have this Entity
@Entity
public class MealPlanADay {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    //@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = false)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Recipe.class)
    @MapKeyEnumerated()
    private Map<Meal,List<Recipe>> recipes=new EnumMap<>(Meal.class);

//Other fields 


    public Map<Meal, List<Recipe>> getRecpies() {
        return recipes;
    }

    public void setRecipes(Map<Meal, List<Recipe>> recipes) {
        this.recipes = recipes;
    }
    
    public void AddRecipe(Meal meal,Recipe recipe){
        if(this.recipes.containsKey(meal)){
            List<Recipe> recipesList = this.recipes.get(meal);
            recipesList.add(recipe);
            this.recipes.put(meal, recipesList);
        }else{
            this.recipes.putIfAbsent(meal, List.of(recipe));
        }
    }
    
    public void removeRecipe(Meal meal,Recipe recipe){
        if(this.recipes.containsKey(meal)){
            List<Recipe> recipesList = this.recipes.get(meal);
            recipesList.remove(recipe);
            this.recipes.put(meal, recipesList);
        }else{
            
        }
    }

Meal is an enum ex "Breakfast,Lunch,Dinner". Recipe is another normal entity.
My goal is for each Meal lunch or dinner,can have multiple recipes associated with that Meal enum.
The result DDL of this code above is this table MEAL_PLANADAY
USER_ID
ID
NOTES

and table MEAL_PLANADAY_RECIPES
RECIPES_KEY
MEAL_PLANADAY_ID
RECIPES_ID

It looks wrong since I have a list of recipes not a single recipe. also persisting this MealPlanADay entity result in
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Long org.omar.recipes.recipe.entity.Recipe.id] by reflection for persistent property [org.omar.recipes.recipe.entity.Recipe#id] : [Recipe{id=13, name=Easy Chicken Salad, category=Lunch,Dinner,Breakfast}]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:341)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:565)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:794)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:676)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:426)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy150.save(Unknown Source)
    at org.omar.recipes.MealPlanner.controller.MealPlannerService.RequestPlan(MealPlannerService.java:106)
    at org.omar.recipes.MealPlanner.boundery.MealPlannerController.RequestMealPlan(MealPlannerController.java:36)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:830)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.run(VirtualThread.java:309)
Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Long org.omar.recipes.recipe.entity.Recipe.id] by reflection for persistent property [org.omar.recipes.recipe.entity.Recipe#id] : [Recipe{id=13, name=Easy Chicken Salad, category=Lunch,Dinner,Breakfast}]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.BasicEntityIdentifierMappingImpl.getIdentifier(BasicEntityIdentifierMappingImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4570)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4135)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EntityIdentifierMapping.getIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(EntityIdentifierMapping.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.SimpleForeignKeyDescriptor.getAssociationKeyFromSide(SimpleForeignKeyDescriptor.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ManyToManyCollectionPart.decompose(ManyToManyCollectionPart.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.BasicCollectionPersister.applyInsertRowValues(BasicCollectionPersister.java:450)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.mutation.InsertRowsCoordinatorStandard.insertRows(InsertRowsCoordinatorStandard.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.BasicCollectionPersister.recreate(BasicCollectionPersister.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:632)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1403)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2319)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:1976)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:561)
    ... 104 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not get java.lang.Long field org.omar.recipes.recipe.entity.Recipe.id on java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleFieldAccessorImpl.newGetIllegalArgumentException(MethodHandleFieldAccessorImpl.java:86)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(MethodHandleObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:48)
    ... 129 more

As for this error I don't know why its happening since I the id of recipe IS accessible. and normal Repository of this entity is working fine.
Should I rethink my MealPlanADay entity or is there solution for this?
Thank you.

Looks like it don't like map containing list. You may use ManyToMany for this case.

You mean normal ManyToMany relation not using map at all?

If you can use just ManyToMany it will be easier.
